# Close connections to DB with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have some code to auto delete and renew a database using LINQ.

```
KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();
if (!db.DatabaseExists())
{
    db.DeleteDatabase();
}
db.CreateDatabase();
```

However, it sometimes fails due to open copnnections. In SQL Management Studio, I can force it to kill the connections but I see no such option in LINQ.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataContext should always be "destroyed" or Disposed, so optimally you should use the Context object inside an using statement:

```
 using(KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext())
 {
    if (!db.DatabaseExists())
    {
        db.DeleteDatabase();
    }
    db.CreateDatabase();
  }
```

This will automatically dispose the context after using it.

To directly dispose it, call the method:

```
 db.Dispose();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use some code for close current connection of sql server in LINQ

```
DBDataContext db= new DBDataContext ();
```

after complete your action you can dispose the db

```
db.Dispose();
```

Comment: What does this answer add to the current accepted one?